# JetBrains Rider Entity framework tools not found

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

I have installed JetBrains Rider on Linux Mint and tried to run migration from Rider Entity framework but it is not available in the project context menu. Please see the screenshot:

[image]

My project is ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2

Answer (score 1):

More detailed visual way of fixing this problem is here by JetBrains team: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2022/01/31/entity-framework-core-inside-rider-ui-way/

Comment: I did that and it didn't work, can you show the full name of the package please?

Comment: Updated my answer, please follow the steps given in the link above